# Amazon Alexa: Having sessions of indefinite length

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am building an alexa skill. But I do not like to say the skill name like "Alexa ask [Skill Name] to [Do Action]" everytime I want to use it. I know sessions help in overcoming this to some extent. I found after googling that a session can be kept open for 8 seconds of inactivity. Here are my questions:

1. Can we control the length of the session? I do not want the session to end after 8 seconds (or whatever time Amazon has set). I want to customize this time. Actually, it would be best if it closes after the user tells it to. Is there a way do it?
2. Is there a way to make alexa invoke a skill basing on intent? For e.g. If I say "Alexa, book a cab for me " it should directly start Uber skill without me requiring to tell it explicitly to use Uber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, we cannot configure the `session-out` time. Its 8 seconds and if you have a `reprompt` you will get few more seconds. However, you can try some hacks like playing a silent audio for sometime in the background. But you will have to use the wake-up word "Alexa" in between to give a command.
2. Yes, `Name-free Interaction` can be enabled using `CanFulfillIntentRequest` request type. This feature is currently available for English (U.S.) skills only and is **offered as a public preview/beta** and may improve or change.

More info on Name-free Interaction [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/understand-name-free-interaction-for-custom-skills.html)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. I need some help in implementing it though. Looks like this is going to be another question on its own. So will ask separately. Thanks!

Comment: I have posted the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530863/alexa-implementing-canfulfillintentrequest-in-python

Comment: Does this work with an echo device or alexa simulator? It worked for me only when i tested it by sending a manual JSON from alexa developer console. Is this a current limitation which will be resolved in further development cycle?