# Alexa - Implementing CanFulfillIntentRequest in python

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have enabled the CanFulfillIntentRequest from the alexa skill developer console in English(U.S) of my skill. I have added a handler in my lambda for the CanFulfillIntentRequest. When I use the skill tester and type the intent utterance directly (without skill invocation name), it doesn't seem to hit my code. I can't find any related logs in the cloudwatch.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("event.session.application.applicationId=" +
          event['session']['application']['applicationId'])

    if event['session']['new']:
        on_session_started({'requestId': event['request']['requestId']},
                           event['session'])

    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return on_intent(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_session_ended(event['request'], event['session'])
    elif event['request']['type'] == "CanFulfillIntentRequest":
        return on_canfullfill(event['request'], event['session'])

def on_canfullfill(request, session):
    print ("Yes, I can!")
```

I know this has to respond back with a JSON specifying if the skill can or cannot take up this request. But shouldn't there be a  - 'Yes, I can!' entry in the cloud watch logs?

What am I missing here? Also, where can I find documentation/apis on forming and sending the reponse for this request?

Comment: I used alexa simulator (not manual JSON ) in the test tab of amazon developer console to test this. Will that be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can only test `CanFulfillIntentRequest` using `Manual JSON` tab from developer console and using `ASK CLI`.

From Alexa documentation

> You cannot test CanFulfillIntentRequest with an Alexa-enabled device

More on testing `CanFulfillIntentRequest`  [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/implement-canfulfillintentrequest-for-name-free-interaction.html#invoke-and-test-the-skill)

Comment: Is it like we have to publish the skill in order for this to work? or dev skills also should be caught with this?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Gonna submit one of my skill with CanFulfillIntentRequest. Lets see how its work when skill is live